# I can not print on Windows 7 shared printer

Tags: 12.04, networking, printing, samba, hp

For a while I can not print from my Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit pc on a Windows 7 shared printer. Before that everything was ok. The printer is HP LaserJet 1100.
The error message is: "File "/usr/lib/cups/backend/smb" not available: No such file or directory"
I have tried to reinstall the samba, I have configured the workgroup properly. I have tried to reinstall the printer on the Ubuntu machine with the proper address, or with lpd (I have read somewhere). If I restart the printer on the cups web interface ("Resume Printer") the problem seems to be solved, but not. (The printer seems to be idle, and if I want to print, I still get the error message.) I have checked the share rights on the Windows 7 pc, and I think it is ok.